# Как собрать APK с поддержкой x64

Tags: android, gradle, apk

При публикации приложения в Google Play появилась ошибка:

> Ошибка
>   Этот выпуск не соответствует требованиям Google Play к 64-разрядным приложениям.
>
> Следующие файлы APK или наборы App Bundle доступны для 64-разрядных устройств, но содержат только 32-разрядный нативный код: 203.
>
> Включите в приложение 64-разрядный и 32-разрядный нативный код. Используйте формат публикации "Набор Android App Bundle", чтобы каждое устройство скачивало только соответствующий его архитектуре нативный код. Это поможет уменьшить общий размер приложения. Подробнее…

Для устранения ошибки использовал `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'` в build.gradle.

**Но одна из библиотек отсутствует в директориях /lib/x86_64 и /lib/arm64-v8a/**

Ниже скрин APK Analyzer:

[image: APK Analyzer]

**UPD 1**
Нативный код используется в одной из используемых библиотек. Ниже оставил зависимость, библиотека из которой не собирается под x64.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'ooo.cron.dagestan'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 202
        versionName "2.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    implementation "com.github.lespinsideg:SimplePanorama:0.3.1"
    ...
    implementation project(path: ':domain')
    implementation project(path: ':data')
}
```

Также ниже фрагмент лога:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ooo.cron.dagestan-87Y2xvDJwseiKSW0mp1u5A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ooo.cron.dagestan-87Y2xvDJwseiKSW0mp1u5A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ooo.cron.dagestan-87Y2xvDJwseiKSW0mp1u5A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libglues.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at com.panoramagl.opengl.GLUES.<clinit>(GLUES.java:31)
        at com.panoramagl.opengl.GLUES.gluNewQuadric(GLUES.java:38)
        at com.panoramagl.PLQuadricPanoramaBase.initializeValues(PLQuadricPanoramaBase.java:43)
        at com.panoramagl.PLSphericalPanorama.initializeValues(PLSphericalPanorama.java:37)
        at com.panoramagl.PLObjectBase.<init>(PLObjectBase.java:28)
        at com.panoramagl.PLObject.<init>(PLObject.java:44)
        at com.panoramagl.PLRenderableElementBase.<init>(PLRenderableElementBase.java:27)
        at com.panoramagl.PLSceneBase.<init>(PLSceneBase.java:40)
        at com.panoramagl.PLPanoramaBase.<init>(PLPanoramaBase.java:32)
        at com.panoramagl.PLQuadricPanoramaBase.<init>(PLQuadricPanoramaBase.java:26)
        at com.panoramagl.PLSphericalPanorama.<init>(PLSphericalPanorama.java:31)
        at com.lespinside.simplepanorama.view.SphericalView.setPanorama(SphericalView.java:74)
        at ooo.cron.dagestan.fragments.PlaceAVFragment.setBitmap(PlaceAVFragment.java:65)
        at ooo.cron.dagestan.activities.MainActivity.setPortraitBitmap(MainActivity.java:281)
        at ooo.cron.dagestan.views.MainView$$State.setPortraitBitmap(MainView$$State.java:228)
        at ooo.cron.dagestan.presenters.MainPresenter$3.onResourceReady(MainPresenter.java:685)
        at ooo.cron.dagestan.presenters.MainPresenter$3.onResourceReady(MainPresenter.java:681)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onResourceReady(SingleRequest.java:582)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onResourceReady(SingleRequest.java:544)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.callCallbackOnResourceReady(EngineJob.java:152)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$CallResourceReady.run(EngineJob.java:398) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
2019-12-31 17:33:40.452 3336-3900/? E/PanoramaGL - PLRenderableElementBase::render: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.panoramagl.opengl.GLUES
        at com.panoramagl.opengl.GLUES.gluUnProject(GLUES.java:205)
        at com.panoramagl.PLSceneBase.createRayWithPoint(PLSceneBase.java:421)
        at com.panoramagl.PLSceneBase.endRender(PLSceneBase.java:354)
        at com.panoramagl.PLRenderableElementBase.render(PLRenderableElementBase.java:164)
        at com.panoramagl.PLRenderer.renderScene(PLRenderer.java:266)
        at com.panoramagl.PLRenderer.render(PLRenderer.java:316)
        at com.panoramagl.PLRenderer.onDrawFrame(PLRenderer.java:476)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1575)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270)
```

Comment: 1) Покажите полностью build.gradle 2) Есть ли в проекте нативные (сишные) исходники, если да, то покажите скрипты сборки ndk

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar Добавил. Скрипты сборки ndk пока не использовал.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в самой библиотеке нет поддержки x64: https://github.com/lespinsideg/SimplePanorama/issues/6. Варианты: найти и переписать на другую, взять [исходники](https://github.com/lespinsideg/panoramagl) нативной библиотеки и добавить поддержку сборки x64

Comment: @woesss что самое интересное, если не прописывать в ndk фильтре поддержку х64, то устройства с х64 работают с библиотекой из armeabi и все работает прекрасно. Потому и думаю, можно ли собрать так, чтобы библиотеки собирались в папки для х64. Планирую пересобрать саму библиотеку.

Comment: Про `x86` можете вообще не заморачиваться, `arm64-v8a` только имеет значение. Современные мобильные Intel процессоры умеют эмулировать ARM и запускать нативный код.

Comment: Вот тут уже кто-то все проблемы решил: https://github.com/marianmoldovan/panoramagl/issues/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, Eugene Krivenja!
В данном случае скачал архив с необходимой библиотекой под x64 (
[решение проблеммы](https://github.com/marianmoldovan/panoramagl/issues/9)).
Создал папку в нужном моделе в src/main папку jniLibs и добавил соответствующие файлы и все заработало.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]